# Vuejs devtools beta shows that inspection is disabled

Tags: vue.js

I've installed the beta of Vue.js devtools in both Chrome and Microsoft Edge.  When I load a vue web page that I'm running locally it shows

```
Vue.js is detected on this page.
Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.
```

I've also tried setting

`app.config.devTools = true;`

in `main.js` but it has no effect.

This is for Vue.js 3.

Is there a Vue devtools browser extension that works with Vue 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue tools finally started working again after I did a `yarn install` on the project.